# Finite quotient of a manifold

Tags: manifolds, group-actions

Suppose you have a real manifold M, and a group G acting *freely* on it. Suppose the quotient $M/G$ is finite. It is true that, as intuition suggest, the space $M/G$ is then discrete?

**Edit**: I added the "free" hypothesis thanks to the example of "Lord Shark the Unknown"

Answer (score 0):

How about $M=\Bbb R$ and $G=\Bbb R^*$ acting on $M$ by multiplication.
The quotient has two points, but I reckon it's not discrete.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I will slightly change the hypothesis because I know what my group is like. In particular, it acts freely, which is not true in your example.

Comment: If furthermore you find this to be not true, I will explicitly write the action!